# How to properly assign serial output to value with ser.readlines for further usage?

Tags: python, regex, sqlite, logging, pyserial

I am newbie and wrote a script, which initiates communication ("/?!") to an energy meter through serial USBport and reads out the incoming energy log. It extracts different values from the output and writes those into a local sqlite-db. It is suppose to run as a cronjob every 15min. A php-website will visualize the sqlite-stored energy readings as a graph btw.

At the moment I don't have access to the meter, it is very remote and cold there, so I need to have it right before I go there.
If I am trying to execute script it raises Error: *ser.readlines(eol='!')* = *z*
*SyntaxError: can't assign to function call*

**is my reading with ser.readlines of the serial output and assigning to value z wrong?**
the script (regex & inserting into DB) works if I open a logfile with similiar values in it: e.g.     `with open ("log") as z:..`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import serial  
import time  
import re  
import sqlite3  

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 300, bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=2)
ser.open()

ser.write("/?!")  
time.sleep(0.001)  
ser.write("\r")    

connection = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/dbname.db')  
cursor = connection.cursor()  
extrakt = []

ser.readlines(eol='!') = z   
for line in z:  
            match = re.search(r'(0\.0\.0|1\.6\.1|1\.8\.1)\(([0-9\.]+)', line)  
            if match: 
                    version,value = match.groups() 
                    extrakt.append(value)

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO energielog (sernr, peak, kwh) values (?, ?, ?)', extrakt)
connection.commit()

ser.close()  
cursor.close()  
connection.close()
```

Comment: ser.readlines does what it says, reads lines from the serial port, it will not write to it. What is the line `ser.readlines(eol='!') = z` supposed to achieve? ser.write will write to the port.

Comment: Dear Danny, ser.readlines is suppose to read the serial output which looks like: 0.1.2*28(1007010000)
0.1.2*27(1006010000) and to put it into z, that the regex can extract the needed values out of the output for storing it in sqlite-db

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of

```
ser.readlines(eol='!') = z
for line in z:
```

you probably want

```
for line in ser.readlines(eol='!'):
```

Comment: i think that did it, thank you very much Hugh. It still amazes how perfection in programming correlates with simplicity. nice!